# How to get updated value of the width and height after rotating the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

My app has view A is the superview of view B, and, setting up the constraints of the width of view B is one-third of view A's width. In the class of view B, 
I write the code in method

```
-(void)updateConstraints {
    //set the constraints of the width of view B is one-third of view A's width
}
```

In the class of View A, I override the method

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

    [viewB setNeedsUpdateConstraints]
    [viewB updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

When making a rotation, the method *updateConstraints* in view B's class get called but the width of view A is still the old value. 
My desired value is new value of the width of view A after rotating the screen. 
It resulted in the constraints of the width of view B is wrong because it depends on **the old value** of the width of view A.

I have two questions as below:

> 1. How to get the updated value of the width/height after rotating screen?
> 2. According to the Apple docs, when call [viewA updateConstraintsIfNeeded] it will update the constraints of itself and **all of its subviews**.
>     But in fact, the method *updateConstraints* in viewB'class - the subview of class A - not get called. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

The method is called view*Will*TransitionToSize:, which means the rotation hasn't happened yet.  Any frame values will be the old size at that point.  You can store the value of the passed-in size and use that, I suppose, since that will be the eventual size.  updateConstraints should be called naturally during a rotation, so you shouldn't need to force it, especially not calling updateConstraintsIfNeeded yourself.

However... if you are trying to use a view's frame width as part of calculating constraint values, you are already off track.  The entire point of constraints is that the solution to their equation will result in the frames for all views; you cannot use the answer to that equation to configure the equation in the first place.  You will perpetually be using the old value, since the constraints must be set up before the frames can be calculated.  All views on the screen are calculated at the same time; most every time you try to use any frame values to set up constraints you will end up with problems.  Every now and then you can get lucky, but it's not recommended.

However, it should be easy to set up a constraint once for the relationship you want (View B being 1/3 the width of View A), and not do anything else programmatically.  Simply set up a constraint with the two being equal widths, with a multiplier of 1/3.

`[viewB.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:viewA.widthAnchor multiplier:1.0/3.0].active = YES;`

You can also do it easily in IB; just add a constraint for viewB to equal superview's width, then go edit the constraint to add "1/3" as the multiplier.  That should achieve the goal with no code at all.